# JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.1.0.GA adding custom log handler

Tags: jboss

I am trying to add a custom log handler to the JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.1.0.GA using a [tutorial](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingACustomLoggingHandlerInJBOSSAs710Final). However, when I add my module to the joboss modules, and update the standalone.xml for the custom log handler and then starting jboss, it crashes.Below is the custom log module.xml and standalone.xml configuration. In the standalone.xml, my custom handler is configured under the custom handler tag.

**module.xml**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="siteelf.loggers">
 <resources>      
               <resource-root path="SiteElfCustomLogger.jar"/>  
              <!-- Insert resources here -->   
         </resources>    
         <dependencies>      
              <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>  
              <module name="javax.api"/>   
         </dependencies>  
</module>
```

**standalone.xml**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.2">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="ALL"/>
        <encoding value="UTF-8"/>
        <formatter>
          <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{dd MMM HH:mm:ss} %-5p -- %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
     </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler autoflush="true" name="FILE">
            <level name="ALL"/>
            <encoding value="UTF-8"/>
            <formatter>
              <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{dd MMM HH:mm:ss} %-5p -- %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
                <file path="server.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>   
        <custom-handler class="com.org.siteelf.core.log.SiteElfMainLogger" module="siteelf.loggers" name="CustomLogger">  
                <level name="ERROR"/>  
                <formatter>  
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>  
                </formatter>  
        <file path="server.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir"/>    
                <properties>  
                    <property name="logFile" value="/usr/share/jboss7/standalone/log/server.log"/>  
                    <property name="debugMode" value="true"/>  
                </properties>  
            </custom-handler>   
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="OFF"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="OFF"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="INFO"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="INFO"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="OFF"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="OFF"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="ALL"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
```

Comment: What exception is thrown when JBoss crashes?

Comment: Thanks Disco for given time to my issue. I got the issue resolved. I had created the module file with the .zip extention while jboss was looking for .jar extension.